# Radio buttons and text orientation

Tags: html, css, radio-button

How can I move the text of a radio button closer to the button itself? When I create a radio button, the button text appears about 10px away from the button, making the horizontal orientation awkward because the text then begins to overlap onto the button to the right.

How can I change the distance of the text from the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note in the below `style="margin:0;"`

`<input type="radio" style="margin:0;" value="radio" id="radio" name="radio" />Some Text`

If you want to do this with a class I'd recommend wrapping the radio buttons because type selectors don't work in all browsers:

```
    <style type="text/css">
      .nomarginradio input{ margin:0; }
    </style>
    <div class="nomarginradio">
      <input type="radio" value="radio" id="radio" name="radio" />Some Text
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a span tag on the text of the input button. and adjust its selectors padding or margin.
Some text